# Unitils dataset and modified dates

Tags: testing, dataset, dbunit, unitils

Any ideas how this can be done with Unitils dbunit?
[Date relative to current in the DBUnit dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856840/date-relative-to-current-in-the-dbunit-dataset)

The problem is that the [create_date]-placeholder is not recognized in @Dataset.

Comment: You're question is a bit vague.  What have you tried so far?  Could you provide the logs or a description of what is happening?

Comment: I made this more of I need an example of using relative dates in unitils dataset -question. I have tried some code copied from the link provided, but getting errors about using []-placeholder in my xml.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution might be to just use placeholders in your xml dataset, eg.

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<dataset>
    <user userName="jdoe" name="doe" firstname="john" lastLogin="{YESTERDAY}" />
    <user userName="jdoe" name="doe" firstname="jane" lastLogin="{A_WEEK_AGO}" /> 
</dataset>

and do some post-processing(replace the placeholders with the calculated values) before you run your tests. When you are using Maven, you could then first execute the post-processing, (fill in the values in the xml-template-dataset, copy the filled-in-xml-dataset to the correct folder), before any tests are executed.